# named scope overriding attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model of `Container` which has_and_belongs_to_many `Papers` which has_one `Status`.

I want to have a named scope on the `Container` model that will give me all the containers populated with only the papers containing a particular set of statuses.

I have something like the following (pseudocode) on the Container model

```
scope :by_status, -> (statuses) do {
    joins(papers:[:paper_statuses]).where('paper_statuses.tag in (?)', statuses) if statuses.present?
}
```

The return that I get is all of the papers in the container regardless of status.. however the strange part is all of the statuses become what I pass in as long as one exists. What would cause this and how can I prevent the overwriting and loading all of the papers in my container object if all I care about are the ones with the particular statuses?

Answer (score 0):

By creating named scope on `Container` model you will always get all `Containers` that contain at least one `Paper` with given status.

But after you call `@containers.first.papers` you will get all papers of that `Container` object regardless their (papers) statuses. That is expected behaviour.
I have similar structure and I can't replicate replacing statuses in my objects.

To be sure what is going on use `explain` method to show your SQL query.
And please paste the code that you use to collect `Container` objects and their `Papers`.

And last thought, maybe it would be better to move the named scope to `Paper` model? That way you may collect `Papers` with statuses you care about with code:

`Container.first.papers.by_status(statuses)`

I hope that my answer will somehow help you. Cheers!